# Qt save image with one channel not possible?

Tags: qt, bmp, grayscale, qimage

I have a buffer filled with some image data (640x480 pixels, one channel [grayscale]). I want to write this image to my disk using Qt (as BMP or PNG).

Expected size BMP: 300 kilobytes

Actual size BMP: 900 kilobytes

It seems that Qt's save method cannot handle images with one channel. Is this a known Qt bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
QImage const img((char const *)data, image.width, image.height, QImage::Format_Grayscale8)
QPixmap::fromImage(img).save(path, "BMP")
```

I tried to use Qt 5.3 and 5.7

edit:
Using this eight years old workaround seems to work http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-10237.html, but the image looks too bright :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem arises because you're *not* saving the `QImage` -- you're converting it to a `QPixmap` and then saving that.  It appears to be the `QImage` to `QPixmap` conversion that causes the format change.

If you want to save as a greyscale bmp file then simply save the `QImage`.